# Read from stdin and write to variable in R

Tags: r, stdout, stdin

How I can write an integer from first line of stdin to variable `n`, and second line `4 -4 1` like this one `c(4, -4, 1)` to second variable?

For example, my input is:

```
2
4 -4 1
```

And I need to get:

```
n = 2
a = c(4, -4, 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
n1 <- readline("Please enter the first line: ")
n2 <- readline("Please enter the second line: ")
n <- as.numeric(n1)
n2 <- unlist(strsplit(n2," "))
a <- c(as.numeric(n2))

#Please enter the first line: 2
#Please enter the second line: 4 -4 1
#> a
#[1]  4 -4  1
#> n
#[1] 2
#> class(a)
#[1] "numeric"
#> class(n)
#[1] "numeric"
```